# Create object from require with Node.js

Tags: node.js, require

I am trying to create an object from the required file Account.js. Node.js displays an error on line `var test = new account();` : Account is not defined. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Account.js
module.exports = function Account() {
  console.log("THIS SHOULD WORK");
}

// app.js
require('./Account');
var test = new Account();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that require isn't like `import` or `include`. This is what you're missing:

```
// app.js
var Account = require('./Account');
var test = new Account();
```